# If $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|=0$, then $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

My question is this:

> If $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|=0$, does it follow that  $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=0$?

If not can someone give an example?
Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Is it $n\to 0$ or $n\to \infty$?

Comment: $n \in \mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R^+$, is $a_n$ a $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ function?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.  Then, $a_n \to 0$ (so in particular $\limsup a_n = 0$).  But $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, so $a_n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence $a_n=(\frac{1}{2})^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=2^{-n}$. Then 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$
but $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$, so 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$$